# I am trying to compare rows of data within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has rows with id and admit dates - I need to compare the dates and get data of admit dates within 30 days of each other

```
ID        Date
--------------------
1         05/01/2023
2         06/12/2023
2         05/17/2023
2         08/01/2023
3         06/01/2023
3         06/15/2023
3         07/10/2023
```

I have created view of distinct ID with date (but could not do an order by with a create as) I read same table with join to view, but I am getting duplicates.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with sample data and expected result? [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: whats the name of the table ?

Comment: You've provided your data. Where is the desired result?

Comment: SQL Server Management [Studio] is an IDE, not a database engine, and is immaterial to your question. You're better off specifying the version of SQL Server you're running. You can get that by pasting the results of running the following against your instance: `select @@version`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to list those admissions with nearby matches, you can use the `EXISTS()` predicate.

```
SELECT D.*
FROM Data D
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT D2.*
    FROM Data D2
    WHERE D2.ID = D.ID
    AND D2.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -30, D.Date) AND DATEADD(day, 30, D.Date)
    AND D2.Date <> D.Date -- Using a unique admission ID here would be better
)
ORDER BY D.ID, D.Date
```

Results:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-05-17 |
| 2 | 2023-06-12 |
| 3 | 2023-06-01 |
| 3 | 2023-06-15 |
| 3 | 2023-07-10 |

If you also want to include specifics of the closest preceding or following admission, you can use `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ...)`. An `OUTER APPLY` is like a `LEFT JOIN` to a subselect.

```
SELECT D.*, PRIOR.Date as PriorDate, NEXT.Date as NextDate
FROM Data D
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 D2.*
    FROM Data D2
    WHERE D2.ID = D.ID
    AND D2.Date >= DATEADD(day, -30, D.Date)
    AND D2.Date < D.Date
    ORDER BY D2.Date DESC
) PRIOR
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 D2.*
    FROM Data D2
    WHERE D2.ID = D.ID
    AND D2.Date > D.Date
    AND D2.Date <= DATEADD(day, 30, D.Date)
    ORDER BY D2.Date
) NEXT
-- WHERE (PRIOR.Date IS NOT NULL OR NEXT.Date IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY D.ID, D.Date
```

Results:

| ID | Date | PriorDate | NextDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | null | null |
| 2 | 2023-05-17 | null | 2023-06-12 |
| 2 | 2023-06-12 | 2023-05-17 | null |
| 2 | 2023-08-01 | null | null |
| 3 | 2023-06-01 | null | 2023-06-15 |
| 3 | 2023-06-15 | 2023-06-01 | 2023-07-10 |
| 3 | 2023-07-10 | 2023-06-15 | null |

The `LAG()` and `LEAD()` window functions can also be used.

```
SELECT D.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) AS PriorDate,
        LEAD(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) AS NextDate
    FROM Data
) D
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, D.PriorDate, D.Date) <= 30
OR DATEDIFF(day, D.Date, D.NextDate) <= 30
ORDER BY D.ID, D.Date
```

Results:

| ID | Date | PriorDate | NextDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-05-17 | null | 2023-06-12 |
| 2 | 2023-06-12 | 2023-05-17 | 2023-08-01 |
| 3 | 2023-06-01 | null | 2023-06-15 |
| 3 | 2023-06-15 | 2023-06-01 | 2023-07-10 |
| 3 | 2023-07-10 | 2023-06-15 | null |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/txD3ANwF).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hint. And hopefully an example of how to lay out your question to get better answers here. And a dbfiddle notebook is always lovely. https://dbfiddle.uk/PahXd98E

There are many nuances that a reproducible example would clear up. I could interpret your question and expected result probably 5 different ways.

Summary: This will give you all the ids which have, for the same id, N number of rows. One for each record with the same id and a _date less than or equal to 30 days in the future.

**Input:**

```
id  _date
1   2023-05-01
2   2023-06-12
2   2023-05-17
2   2023-05-15
2   2023-08-01
3   2023-06-01
3   2023-06-15
3   2023-07-10
```

**Code to help reproduce:**

```
create table id_date (
  id integer,
  _date date
);

insert into id_date (id,_date) values (1, cast('2023-05-01' as date));
insert into id_date (id,_date) values (2, cast('2023-06-12' as date));
insert into id_date (id,_date) values (2, cast('2023-05-17' as date));
insert into id_date (id,_date) values (2, cast('2023-05-15' as date));
insert into id_date (id,_date) values (2, cast('2023-08-01' as date));
insert into id_date (id,_date) values (3, cast('2023-06-01' as date));
insert into id_date (id,_date) values (3, cast('2023-06-15' as date));
insert into id_date (id,_date) values (3, cast('2023-07-10' as date));
```

**Expected:**

```
select t1.id,
       t1._date as original_date,
       t2._date as later_date_within_30_days
  from id_date t1
 inner
  join id_date t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id 
   and t2._date > t1._date -- strict inequality so avoid the record picking
                             -- up itself.
   and t2._date <= DATEADD(day, 30, t1._date)
```

Result

```
id  original_date   later_date_within_30_days
2   2023-05-17      2023-06-12
2   2023-05-15      2023-05-17
2   2023-05-15      2023-06-12
3   2023-06-01      2023-06-15
3   2023-06-15      2023-07-10
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution using SQL server. Though your requirement is not very clear still I tried and came up with something which might help you get your answer. What first_id , second_id , first_date , second_date say here is the comparison between two ids and their dates. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
    with prepare_data as
    (
    select a.id as first_id , b.id as second_id ,  
           a.admit_date as first_date , b.admit_date as second_date ,
           abs(DATEDIFF(day,a.admit_date,b.admit_date)) as diff  from
        (
            select id , convert(date , dt , 101) as admit_date from admit_dt
        ) as a , 
        (
            select id , convert(date , dt , 101) as admit_date from admit_dt
        ) as b
    where a.id <> b.id and abs(DATEDIFF(day,a.admit_date,b.admit_date))  <= 30
    )
    select 
           distinct case when first_id < second_id then first_id else second_id end as first_id ,
           case when first_id > second_id then first_id else second_id end as second_id ,
           case when first_date < second_date then first_date else second_date end as first_date , 
           case when first_date > second_date then first_date else second_date end as second_date ,  
           diff
    from prepare_data;
```

[image]